# get SMS history between specific twilio's phone and specific outbound phone TWILIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

Let's say I have 5 twilio's phone number, where I can send SMS to users. Is there any way to retrieve directly the list ordered by date from the SMS history of those number specifically, or I need to do 2 calls to the API inverting the from and to parameter, and after that, mix both of the data in an array and sort them by date.

Let say i want something like this ( does not work but you can see want i am trying to do)

```
client.messages.each({
    from: '14509153021' || '+5945863945',
    to: '+5945863945' || '14509153021',
},
    messages => {
      console.log(messages)
    }
);
```

I have this code snippet below that works, but i have to manually sort them by date and mix them in the same array to display correctly the history to my user interface :

```
client.messages.each({
  from: '+5945863945',
  to: '+14509153021',
},

    messages => {
      //add to temporary array 
    }

);

client.messages.each({
  from: '14509153021',
  to: '+5945863945',
},

    messages => {
      //add to temporary array 
    }

);

//mix all data to the same array ordered by date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid you've answered your own question here. You need to do two calls to the API, inverting the `From` and `To` numbers.

Alternatively, you could just list all your messages and filter out by `To` and `From` numbers.

Comment: Yea this confirms my thought ! Thank you !

Comment: But since client.messages.each({...}) is asynchronous I believe, and I actually have no idea how much messages I am waiting for, how can I wait until all messages has been retrieved before sending back to user interface ? The goal is to copy like android SMS display, so I need all message to be displayed in my user interface, ordered by date

Comment: It is probably better for you to store these messages, at least the information you want from them, in a database that is local to your application so that you can access them more directly and have more control. If you did pull them directly from the API, as the number of messages increased, the slower your requests would get as you needed to paginate more and more messages.

Comment: Yea, this is what I have finally implemented ! Once the message has been successfully send or received, I add it to my database. Better performance and better usability